# Confusing preposition with words

Tags: compound-words

[Implication of] AND [implication for]

Although I have tried to find the meaning of these two word combinations, it hasn't allowed me to differentiate their meanings properly. Any explanation on their different use-cases is welcomed.

Comment: The implication of this first sentence is that there are at least *some* contexts where ***of*** is the preferred preposition.  But the implications for the OP which follow from that are unclear, since ***for*** is perfectly correct in this second sentence. In short, the question lacks context and evidence of prior research.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please review my answer.

Answer (score 1):

See usage examples for [implication](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/implication) on ODO:

> ‘many people are unaware of the implications **of** such reforms’

vs.

> ‘If this decline is not now arrested, it will have enormous negative implications **for** our economy and society.’

In simple terms, *of* refers to what is causing, whereas *for* refers to what is being effected.

HTH.

Comment: This seems "correct" so far as it goes, but I note that Google Books claims hundreds of written instances of both ["**implications within the economy**"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22implications+within+the+economy%22) and ["**implications within society**"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22implications+within+society%22). Since that would be a perfectly valid alternative to your second example, you could add ***within** refers to where the effects occur*. But would it *really* change the "meaning" to have that revised second example?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've confined myself to comparing the two prepositions. Plus, the OP is new and may not be expecting too complex an answer. As for *within*, there are also other words possible: *against*? *toward*? ....

Comment: Offhand I can't think of any natural contexts for *against* or *toward/s*, but I could certainly imagine contexts where the implications ***to*** me might not be the same as they are for (to?) you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was speaking offhand myself. However, "The policy ... comes under scrutiny because of its **implication towards** scheduling ..."; "There was a shift of formal emphasis in modal logic away from **implication towards** necessity. "; "Interaction of superoxide dismutase with the glycine zipper regions of β-amyloid peptides: is there an **implication towards** Alzheimer's disease ..."; "a perspective on mutation spectrum in ATP7B gene, prevalent defects, clinical heterogeneity and **implication towards** diagnosis."; so on.

Comment: Haha - take a bow! The bottom line is given enough contrived context we can make a case for  just about any preposition. [*He traces the evolution of love and its pervasive **implications through** the ages, beginning with the love rivalries of Venus,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pervasive+implications+through+the+ages%22) for example.